# jQuery return 0 inputs in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I having a strange problem. I am working in Parallels to test a site in IE 9 on Windows 7.

My setup is jQuery 2.1.1, Bootstrap 3.2.

I was validating a form with Parsley which if course worked well in Chrome, but did nothing in IE. When testing further I realized the DOM wasn't even updating at all. So I stripped it out down to just this to see what was happening:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    console.log('ready')
    /*
        The form submit handler
    */
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        fields = $('#promo-form').find(':input');
        console.log($(fields).length)
    });
});

Chrome Console:
ready
15


IE 9 Console (with F12 Developer Tools)
LOG: ready 
LOG: 0
```

I can get IE to recognize some simple selectors like $('input'), $('form') but cannot use jQuery methods to find a collection. All works just fine in Chrome on the Mac.

Any ideas here?
Thank you
Rich

Comment: Try with jQuery 1.11, it works better with IEs.

Comment: Prior to version 2, I was using 1.11 which giving me the same issue.

Comment: @b1j in that case he only select input elements, ":input" selector includes textareas, select and buttons.

Comment: fields.length or $(fields).length return 0 in IE. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried :
http://jsfiddle.net/dhyjwg4L/

Just tested in IE 10 / 11, don't have an IE9 machine to hand.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($("#promo-form :input").length);
});
```

If you didn't want textareas / buttons remove the : before the input, and they wont be counted.

```
$('#promo-form').find(':input');
//Combine the selector to make 
$("#promo-form :input")
```

UPDATE : Have now tested this on IE 8-11, and is working on all of them.

Comment: While I didn't down vote you, I am not sure what's happening. Maybe it's the system or particular version of IE thats the problem. I am running it through Parallels on Mac since I dont have Windows.

Comment: Did the above selector work for you Richard? Rather than using .find add :input to your selector.

Comment: Same result. I'm going to see if I can find a proper Windows setup or checkout a cross browser service like BrowserStack to double check the situation. There's no reason my particular query should have returned zero as it was fine in other browsers.